# Static variable in Java not initializing

Tags: java, bufferedimage, static-members

So I am having trouble with the following code.

```
public class bw {
    public static int checked[][];
    public static BufferedImage input;

    public static void floodfill(int j, int i, int color, int spotColor, int th) throws Exception {
       input.setRGB(j, i, color);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\Lena.png"));       
        checked = new int[input.getHeight()][input.getWidth()];
        floodfill(250, 310, 0, input.getRGB(250,310), 35);
    }
}
```

Have taken out most of the irrelevant part from the code. The checked variable which is static is working fine. But the input variable which I have intialized in the main function is still null. It gived me null pointer exception from floodfill.

Comment: Look into variable shadowing. Your `main` method's local variable is different than your `static` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a local variable with the same name, inside main method as a `local variable` and as a `static attribute`. Therefore your static attribute is not get initialized instead of the `local variable` getting initialized

Comment: beat me to it. Scope means everything, especially in an OOP language like Java. Best to avoid giving two variables the same name when at all possible within a single class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class bw{
    public static int checked[][];
    public static BufferedImage input;

    public static void floodfill(int j, int i, int color, int spotColor, int th) throws Exception{
        input.setRGB(j, i, color);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        input = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\Lena.png"));       
        checked = new int[input.getHeight()][input.getWidth()];
        floodfill(250, 310, 0, input.getRGB(250,310), 35);

    }
}
```

You have declared variable `input` twice, so the input variable inside main method is initialized and the other(the static attribute) is not